# Android App and Open Source Libraries

Tags: android, c++, stl, licensing

I have an existing app(not released public yet just internal) based on c++ which i would like to port to android and use its services in my android app. I use STL and boost in that app.

My question is if i want to port the existing code to android, can i just compile them as static or shared objects.

I was planning to use Android NDK for porting the native c++ code to android as a library, and use it in my android application which is in Java

but because i also use open source libraries and if i use them in my android app's code should i release the source code of my library as well?

I don't understand how these license things usually work when it comes to releasing it as an public app. I guess if i compile it as shared library, i guess i should be fine, but i think there will be some issues when it comes to app upload??(or not maybe??)

Second, if i compile them as static libraries, then i guess i need to release my source object files??

I'm not so comfortable in releasing my source, how can i do this effectively? Which path should i take(shared / static object), or will it not even matter because anyways the application would just be an installer and it should work just fine in any mobile phone?? Will there be any open-source violation issues if i do that??

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to learn Java... and figure out that there is no STL and boost libraries.

The Java ecosystem has its own crowd of opensource libraries you can use to be more productive. Including them in your apps is just like copying a set of .jar files in the right folder and add them in the build path.

About licensing, most issues come with GPL licensed libraries. The GPL license requires any app produced with a GPL component to be also open sourced and licensed with GPL (the famous "contagious" license).

Anyway, the GPL is rarely used for libraries as this full open source requirement would limit their adoption. There is a derived GPL license called LGPL which does not require your apps to be open sourced.

Though, libraries are often distributed under more permissive licenses and most of the time it is not an issue to include them in your apps.

Comment: my bad, i thought with Android NDK we can still port our existing code as aLibrary and get to import it in the main application which is in Java

Comment: Thanks that was good info on licensing part. So i guess i could compile and link boost statically / shared to my c++ library, it wouldn't matter because boost license was very simple. and stl falls under LGPL. Thnx for the info again

Answer (score 0):

Should you format your question a little better? If you are using Open Source Libraries in your existing application, the same rules applies when you use to build the application for Android too.

Just as the poster had mentioned, do not confuse C++ libraries with Java libraries which are required for Android Development. Just do Android using it's SDK and if you are looking for Open Source libraries in the Android world, there is a [list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications#Libraries).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i suppose i edited my post a bit better. No i'm not confusing between java and c++'s open source libs, if i were to use my existing c++ code in my android app, i still would have to compile and link stdc++ and boost as either static / shared libraries right? How would i do that?